# Need to conditionally render a section with X amount of rows depending on user selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component containing a dropdown with options that include `none, 1, 5, and 13`.

Depending on what number the user selects I need to then render a section including that many rows with a field name and dropdown for each. If the user selects none, I need the whole additional configuration section to disappear.

Each dropdown within the new section will feature the same set of options. Each field name will include it's number i.e.

```
Configuration Dropdown #1
```

```
Configuration Dropdown #2
```

```
Configuration Dropdown #3
```

I'm trying to create a function to attach to an onChange for each option within the initial select dropdown, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

I've included a CodeSandbox to better show what I mean.

[image: Edit Q-56776002-Wrong-Import]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/56796511-r3qs9).

It's not perfect but I hope it helps.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Row, Col } from "antd";
import AntCollapse from "./CustomCollapse";

const Button = styled.button`
  color: white;
  background-color: #0076de;
  border-radius: 5px;
`;

const ConfigurationOptions = () => {
  const [configNumber, setConfigNumber] = useState(0);
  const [configList, setConfigList] = useState([]);

  const setConfig = number => {
    console.log(number);
    setConfigNumber(number);
    let newArray = new Array(parseInt(number, 10)).fill(0);
    console.log("newarray", newArray);
    setConfigList(newArray);
  };

  const setList = (number, index) => {
    setConfigList(prevState => {
      let newState = [...prevState];
      newState[index] = parseInt(number, 10);
      return newState;
    });
  };    

  return (
    <AntCollapse header="configuration test">
      <div>
        <h1>Section Header</h1>
        <Row>
          <Col span={4} offset={20}>
            <Button type="submit">Apply to All</Button>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col span={12}>
            <h3>Config Section #1</h3>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col span={12}>
            <p>How many do you need?</p>
          </Col>
          <Col span={4} offset={8}>
            <select
              value={configNumber}
              onChange={e => setConfig(e.target.value)}
            >
              <option value={0}>None</option>
              <option value={1}>1 Option</option>
              <option value={5}>5 Options</option>
              <option value={13}>13 Options</option>
            </select>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col span={12}>
            <h3>Conditional Config Section</h3>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        {configList.map((num, i) => (
          <Row key={i.toString()}>
            <Col span={12}>
              <p>Option Configuration Dropdown</p>
            </Col>
            <Col span={4} offset={8}>
              <select value={num} onChange={e => setList(e.target.value, i)}>
                <option value={0}>Default</option>
                <option value={1}>Add #1</option>
                <option value={2}>Add #2</option>
                <option value={3}>Add #3</option>
              </select>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        ))}
      </div>
    </AntCollapse>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<ConfigurationOptions />, rootElement);
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23387433)

Comment: @MihaiChelaru added the code, thanks for the advice